# Remove highlighting of the tree node when corresponding tab is closed

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a treepanel and a tabpanel. Each tree panel node corresponds to a tabpanel panel. When i click on a node, it gets highlighted and tab panel gets opened. Same way when i close the tab panel, the highlighting of node should be removed. I tried a lot, but could not succeed. Any help on this?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1foo

you can see the listener on `Abc.view.main.explorer.AbcTabPanel` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fq0

Your example threw a couple of errors which i've fixed in my example, but what i've basically done is this: i've attached a `close` listener to the created tab that checks the `TreeList` selection (`getSelection`). If the tab's record is the current selection, set selection to `null`. The TreeList will update its layout and unhighlight that record.

I hope this helps!

p.s. I've also done some minor code changes. That's just my coding style. If you don't like them, ignore them :)

Comment: Great. Inherited some of your coding standards also :). If you see when i close a panel, the previous panel is shown up, can i highlight that in the treelist?

Comment: That's entirely possible. You could use one of these events:

* `tabPanel` [tabchange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#event-tabchange) event.
* tab [activate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.Component.html#event-activate)

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle example to update the selection in the treelist when changing tab. Take a look at the `activate` event handler.
You might want to refactor the tab event handler setup a bit though. Setting up these event handlers creates closures because they use `view` and `record` variables from outside the handler function.